# Does Twig support !=? it doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: php, html, twig, slim

On related twig forums it seems to say that != is supported, but it doesn't work when I used it. I am also using the PHP framework Slim.

Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="edit-module-stackid" id="edit-module-stackid">
    <option value="{{selectedstack.ID}}">{{selectedstack.ID}}</option>
        {% for k,stack in stacks %}
            {%if selectectedstack.ID != stack.ID%}
                <option value="{{stack.ID}}">{{stack.ID}}</option>
            {%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I want to put the selected value at the top (so it is selected).

Then I want to loop over the rest of the list to grab the other stacks where it is not equaled to the selected stack.

As you can see in the image it displays the stack twice.. (1 followed by 1)

Anyone have any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the provided code snippet, it seems to be a typo.

In your code you use `selectedstack.ID` for the first option, but in the loop u compare `selectectedstack.ID` with `stack.ID`